# Delivery place by client relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have this test schema:

[image: Database]

A client can have multiple addresses and multiple contacts 
For example, a secretary (contact) will receive a product purchased by the company (client) she works for.

So, the delivery needs a contact, an address and also needs to be bounded to a client. What's the best way to a `Delivery` know where and whom to deliver its produtcs?

If I attach `Delivery` to `Address` and `Contact`, I'll have 2 `Client` id's.

Comment: add an id_address and id_contact field to the delivery table... also there's a typo in your contact table name ;)

Comment: I agree with Osuwariboy, but want to recommend that you add foreign key constraints on (id_client, id_address) and (id_client, id_contact).  If `Address` and `Contact` have foreign key constraints to `Client` on id_client, that constraint is transitive and doesn't need to be enforced on `Delivery`.